# How can I remove all string spaces in AngularJS binding?

Tags: angularjs

I try to do this:

```
<div id="{{mystring.replace(/[\s]/g, \'\')}}"></div>
```

but its not working. "mystring" is an object on `$scope` with string like "my string is this" with spaces I want to remove from the view.

Comment: [Angular expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) are not simply javascript. So you can't assume that everything that would work in a javascript execution context will also work as a angular expression.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Just create a dedicated filter :

```
angular.module('filters.stringUtils', [])

.filter('removeSpaces', [function() {
    return function(string) {
        if (!angular.isString(string)) {
            return string;
        }
        return string.replace(/[\s]/g, '');
    };
}])
```

and call it like :

```
<div id="{{'hi there'| removeSpaces}}"></div>
```

Comment: hi Cétia, this works fine when I got the data & display on input field (at the time of edit profile). But by using this solution field is non-writable. Please suggest the solution with writable input field. Thanks.

Answer (score 30):

If you simply need it in one or two places it may be easier to split and join:

```
$scope.boundString = 'this is a string with spaces'
```

with that you could do in your template:

```
<span>my string is: {{ boundString.split(' ').join('') }}</span>
```

and you would get:

```
my string is: thisisastringwithoutspaces
```

another approach that has been mentioned is the regex version ('g' is for global):

```
<span>my string is: {{ boundString.replace(/ /g, '') }}</span>
```

I guess the point is that you can do whatever you want to a string within an expression. These examples are bad convention with respect to Angular dirty-checking. In Angular, bound functions (string.replace, string.split) get evaluated differently opposed to a specified value (string, boolean) when bound to a template's expression. The result of a bound function must be evaluated before Angular knows whether or not to update the DOM. This can be costly over a large app. I would suggest using another variable to track the un-spaced value:

```
$scope.noSpaces = $scope.boundString.replace(/ /g, '');
```

HTML:

```
<span>{{ noSpaces }}</span>
```

This way, when a digest loop is triggered, Angular will check if noSpaces has changed as opposed to evaluating boundString.replace(/ /g, '').

What if you are ng-repeating? Good question.

```
for (var idx = 0, idx < $scope.boundIterable.length, i++) {
    $scope.boundIterable[i].noSpaces = $scope.boundIterable[i].boundString.replace(/ /g, '');
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul ng-repeat="iterable in boundIterable">
    <li>{{ iterable.noSpaces }}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 10):

The directive mentioned works pretty well. But if you want to remove spaces for smaller texts, you can use

```
.split(" ").join("")
```

This replaces the complete spaces unlike `.replace(" ","")` which replaces only the first space.

Comment: Clean, nice and easy! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can replace all spaces by blank by using `replace()`:

```
.replace(" ","")
```

Comment: This seems to replace only the first space.

Comment: You were looking for `.replace(/ /g, '')`

Answer (score 2):

How about `{{ string.trim() }}`?

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Comment: This will remove spaces from the start and from the end of the `string`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using `replace()`:

```
{{mystring.replace(" ","")}}
```

that's it I hope so.

Answer (score 0):

```
removeSpaces() {
  originalText ="hi! here i'm";
  removedSpacesText = originalText.split(" ").join("");
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation, how you came to this result.