# Remove White Space in Mat-input for validation

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular2 and trying to remove whiteSpace for required field but how to trim that input filed before validator to check

Comment: What about `value.trim()` ? ...

Comment: i am trying to remove space in html *ngif but not accepting

Comment: What ? Give some code please.

Comment: loginForm.controls.username.value.trim().errors?.email

Comment: email should remove whitespace

Comment: Could you please **post your actual code into your question** and not only one line ?

Comment: i am sorry but i dont have permission to publish code but i need to check email validation

Comment: to remove whitespaces value.trim will work..

Comment: can u give me an example to remove whitespace in Angular 2

Comment: Email validation for mat-input

Comment: "I don't have permission to publish code", yet you just did. And I'm not asking you for passwords and remote accesses, I'm asking you only a piece of HTML code to understand your issue. If you won't post your code, I'll be forced to flag your topic, sorry

Comment: @trichetriche I did your thoughts. **Without code we can't provide proper  solutions**

Comment: add you code to the question, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment of `i am trying to remove space in html *ngif but not accepting`

Please go to use a function for trim

```
trimText(text: string)
{
return text.trim();
}
```

Call the `trimText()` function into your html

```
{{trimText(yourModelName)}}
```

But you can go with a filter for the best approach

take this discussion : [How can I remove all string spaces in AngularJS binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26232826/how-can-i-remove-all-string-spaces-in-angularjs-binding)

Comment: sorry , but i am trying to use mat-input for required Field validation but it Accepts Spaces

Comment: guys Any chance's are there to put two close votes? seriously without code we can't do anything. It will go to off-topic . Sorry