# Can't clear blank spacing in pasted text in Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer

```
  noSpace(event: any, docId: string) { // Muss richtig gemacht !
    let str = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
    let clipBoardStr = event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    let s = clipBoardStr.replace(/ /g , '');
    setTimeout( function() {
       (<HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById(docId)).value = s;
     }, 100);
   }
```

I want to have the text without any white spaces.

This works perfectly on Firefox and Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer  :(

Comment: Where exactly does it break? What does "not work" mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove all string spaces in AngularJS binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26232826/how-can-i-remove-all-string-spaces-in-angularjs-binding)

Comment: @samanime When I paste text with blanks, the aren't removed in IE

Comment: So start to debug, what is happening? Does the method get called?
 What is the initial string, what does it look like after it was replaced? `console.log(escape(str), escape(s))` Also seems weird you are using DOM with angular and not just doing it with a binding.

Comment: @epascarello 
_Unable to get property 'getData' of undefined or null reference_  **and** _ERROR CONTEXT [object Object]_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 let clipBoardStr;
if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.getData) {
  clipBoardStr = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
} else {
  clipBoardStr = event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
}
```

And this is the way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

could you try to change your regexp to /\s+/g ?

```
let s = clipBoardStr.replace(/\s+/g , '');
```

the meta \s match any whitespace character https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace.asp

Comment: Still only in Chrome and Firefox